# Get Geospatial Geometry Coords for City & State or Zipcode

Tags: geolocation, location, geometry, geospatial

Does anyone know if there is somewhere on the internet that i can enter City & State or Zipcode so that i can get the Spatial Geometry Coords for that city and state.

Reason i need this is that i get several files that are imported to our site with City Names abbreviated. So i will have to make the abbreviated citys in the database manually but give the right coord information to our maps and distance calculations.

Here is an example of our database... Below it is Examples of city names that are abreviated.

```
ID CORDS CITY STATE ZIP CREATED UPDATED CS
69629;"0101000020E61000004A24D1CB28A055C097FDBAD39DCD4040";"moody";"al";"35004";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.133281";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.133281";"moody, al"
69630;"0101000020E610000016139B8F6BBD55C0D28C45D3D9CB4040";"adamsville";"al";"35005";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.187562";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.187562";"adamsville, al"
69631;"0101000020E610000093C6681D55CF55C09B92ACC3D1B94040";"adger";"al";"35006";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.1948";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.1948";"adger, al"
69632;"0101000020E6100000AF7C96E7C1B355C07A6F0C01C09D4040";"alabaster";"al";"35007";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.203153";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.203153";"alabaster, al"
69633;"0101000020E6100000EFE192E34E7B55C07714E7A8A3734040";"alexander city";"al";"35010";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.211388";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.211388";"alexander city, al"
69634;"0101000020E6100000E09C11A5BD9155C09357E71890AD4040";"alpine";"al";"35014";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.219605";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.219605";"alpine, al"
69635;"0101000020E6100000DD0720B5899F55C0C11C3D7E6F294140";"arab";"al";"35016";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.228182";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.228182";"arab, al"
69636;"0101000020E6100000CA54C1A8A4A855C0CC6262F371254140";"baileyton";"al";"35019";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.23646";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.23646";"baileyton, al"
69637;"0101000020E610000097C5C4E6E3BC55C09ACC785BE9B34040";"bessemer";"al";"35020";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.244822";"2012-05-31 11:00:34.244822";"bessemer, al"
```

Examples of what was searched that didnt show up in our database

```
"FT SASKATCHEWN, AB"
"Gulfport, MD"
"La Costa Apts, CA"
"Mccarley, NV"
"W Union, SC"
"SUNNY ISLES BEACH, FL"
"Middleton Nh, NH"
"ST ANTONIN, QC"
"ft leonard wood, MO"
"Russellville, OK"
"Pleasant Prairie, PA"
"Chickalah, AR"
"MONTGOMERY COUNTY AREA, PA"
"VERSA COLD, GA"
"Rock Glen, SK"
"Pine Groven Holland, PA"
"Bethelneffs, PA"
"La Folette, TN"
"TRACY, CH"
"Magnolia, MA"
"MONT LAURIER, QC"
"CHATEAUGAY, QC"
"Puebla, MX"
"LaFollette, TN"
"ft hunter ligget, CA"
"ST GENEVIEVE, MO"
```

Comment: What excatly do you mean by "Spatial Geometry Coords" ? Is is just coordinate for a place, or actual polygon showing the area for the place ?

Comment: I get the location from GIS extension on postgresql  looks like this 0101000020E610000097C5C4E6E3BC55C09ACC785BE9B34040

Comment: Still not getting the problem, and what it is that you would actually need..

Comment: what the problem is: I have many files imorted to the site with locations. but when some of the file locations are abrieviated it errors because it can not correspond to the correct record in my database. so i want to add the record for St. Louis, MO for example but my database doesnt have "St. Louis, MO" it only has "Saint Louis, MO" so i want to make another record of the abreviated city name with the right Geospatial Data EX: "0101000020E610000097C5C4E6E3BC55C09ACC785BE9B34040". Also have some that i dont have at all abreviated or not.